# ASP.NET MVC - missing resources after moving them

Tags: resources

I had "Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture..." error message after moving resource files from App_GlobalResources to my custom resources folder. I had this message during the runtime - the compilation runs well. I did it through Visual Studio's Solution Explorer (just drag-and-drop them), so I thought the VS would care about real paths of my resources. I used my own "custom tool namespace" and "Custom tool" PublicResXFileCodeGenerator when I created resources in the App_GlobalResources folder.

So, how to bring all my resources into view without re-adding them?

Comment: You should change the namespaces in using directives.

Comment: I don't understand what did you mean? In controllers, views and another locations where I use my resources, the .NET can't find my resources at the runtime. The compilation runs well. But I just moved resources from App_GlobalResources to my custom Resources folder through Visual Studio's Solution Explorer. The "custom tool" property of my resource keeps the same, and "custom tool namespace" property as well.

Comment: Well, I added some clarity to my question.